# Can a CMS be powered by a Git repository?

Tags: php, git, github, content-management-system

I made a one-off CMS for a client of mine a while ago, however it was powerful enough that I used it again on a number other projects. Now that I need to manage it, I want to be able to update all of the deployments via a single update.

I'm wondering if I might be able to have the CMS simply include files from a GitHub repository. Is there a way to do this? Something like:

```
<?php

require('URL TO MEDIA UPLOAD MODULE AT GITHUB');
require('URL TO PAGE MANAGEMENT MODULE AT GITHUB');
//etc...

?>
```

Eventually the CMS will have a number of different modules for a number of different business types (real estate, retail products & services, etc) that will be included based on the modules listed for the specific deployments needs.

I just want to store everything in one place and have each deployment updated when I commit a change to the repo.

Is this possible? If not, any suggestions?

Comment: it is - but not like you are thinking. continuous integration is a topic you could research. either that or post-commit hooks.

Comment: This isn't a great design, but you could accomplish this most likely by mashing up [simple-php-git-deploy](https://github.com/markomarkovic/simple-php-git-deploy) and [deploy-hook-forker](https://github.com/deadlyicon/deploy-hook-forker).

You're probably better off updating your `CMS` to check for new releases based on version and downloading.

Comment: So a better way would be to host the "master" somewhere, and have a CRON job on the deployed CMSs run nightly to check versions against the master? What then? Simply have each module at a static URL and `file_get_contents` the updated master?

Comment: I would instead advise storing a generalized/generic `configuration file`  over on github, and then just do a git pull into each new instance of your CMS.  That way the internal code/functions/includes/requires stay the same, but the custom configs do not.  The configs should change for each customer anyway I would think.  I used to use a master config called "config.changeme.php" which I tracked in git, and then, once pulled down, use shell to do `mv config.changeme.php config.php` and in the code, it would require config.php

Comment: I've pondered over this type of thing before and here is what my plan was. As you said host the "master" somewhere and have a cron in each of the CMS's that check in. If they check in from a version that is out of date you send back the URL to the update it needs. This URL is simply a zip file containing the same structure of your CMS. It downloads it, loops through it, and the swaps out all the files it finds inside it. If your system is paid then on check-ins it should pass you a generated key you can use to encrypt the updated file if it needs one.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about storing files on Github.

However, I do have another suggestion to get to your goal:

If your projects reside on the same server and you have root access to the server, you could have the core files in 1 location. With symlinks you can have the projects make use of that same directory. You will never have to deploy again since you only have to update 1 set of files.

Just make sure that theres a way to store/load the templates and individual user settings apart from the core files.